# Build is succeed but Agent is still running

Tags: azure-devops

Configured self-hosted Agent skipping sslcertvalidation  as we were facing issue .
Even though build is succeed but Agent is still running ...( In logs it's showing build is successd)
If I check the logs from Agent Machine it's showing "try to append 1 batches web console line for record '96defxxxxxxxxxxxx' , success rate : 1/1

Answer (score 0):

Your self-hosted build agent is always running otherwise you would not be able to contact it from Azure DevOps to trigger builds.
Unless you see any errors or warnings in Azure DevOps you are fine.